# Does a C++ GUI Library that renders to image exist?

Tags: c++, user-interface, bitmap, cross-platform

I'm thinking of a library that would render all custom controls to a bitmap, so the final "gui image" could be applied to a windows form, osx window, or OpenGL texture, etc. Does this exist? I know the other libraries like QT are intermediates that finally use the OS specific control code. I want something that is completely independent of the OS code, and is just layering the custom control graphics onto a final image in memory. I'm thinking this would be the ultimate X-platform GUI library for C++. Thoughts?

PS: I know questions asking for opinions are not really kosher but I googled hard and couldn't find anything. I need some input here.

Thanks!

EDIT: Ok, to clarify that I meant GUI library, I meant the library is given mouse/keyboard events then handles the logic of the typical GUI chain, then it's final render target is a bitmap in memory that I can do stuff with after. It would be  GUI library, not just a canvas.

Comment: Such a library would be of very limited use, so nobody would use it. GUI libraries do much more than draw buttons. They handle logic (should this button be clickable?), interaction (TAB moves to the "next field"), integration (good luck dragging a text from a bitmap onto your web browser), etc.

Comment: @DanielKO: All of those features are completely orthogonal to the feature that the OP is pining for.  They are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: If you are only going to draw buttons and labels, that's not a GUI, that's a basic 2D canvas API. From a GUI library I expect it to be able to redirect input events to the proper entities, handle interactions (clicking, selecting text, scrolling) and only give me back the final results (button was clicked, dialog window was canceled, the final result of a text input field is this std::string).

Comment: I'm trying to be constructive here; I was trying to point out what the concept of a GUI library is, for me, for people who have designed existing GUI frameworks, and for the OP. My point is, if you are only lay-outing and rendering, you are solving a very small problem, most people would not consider it to be a useful GUI.

Comment: @DanielKO: Okay, but he's not saying that the only thing the GUI library would do is rendering.  He's just talking about an alternative way for the rendering in a GUI library to be done.

Comment: @DanielKO I understand, and appreciate the feedback. Thanks. I just thought it would be nice to have a QT/GTK whatever with all the controls implemented where nothing relied on the underlying os, and was completely independant, even independant from render target. But I'm a bit of a noob to GUI programming, so maybe I'm just misinformed. I just want lightweight and portable.

Comment: (after the clarifying edit) I would say any SDL-based (1.2) GUI library falls into that category: they read input events from a generic source, and output to a SDL_Surface (which is just a bitmap). OGRE+OIS-based GUIs would be similar, input comes more or less "generic" from OIS, visual elements are fed into OGRE through textured rectangular shapes suited for OpenGL/DirectX rendering. Case is, at some point you need to read from the input devices, so that won't be cross-platform; and you most likely will want the output to be rendered, so you need GDK at the bottom of GTK+.

Comment: (continued) so on that sense, GTK+ fits the requirements; on all platforms all the event handling, drawing, etc is done by the same code. Then GDK comes in to glue it with the OS. SDL does the same low-level role, as is OGRE+OIS. I would be surprised if Qt didn't work in the same way. I've seen wxWidgets prefer to provide distinct implementations for distinct platforms though, so it's an exception.

Comment: I used GUIchan on top of SDL once; there's also aedGUI. Too bad libsdl.org collapsed due to the 2.0 release, they had a list of GUI libraries.

Comment: The XY problem again? **What are you trying to do?**